# Django check if Form is_valid()

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I am trying to replicate

```
if form.is_valid():
```

With the django form wizard. (this question shouldn't have anything to do with the wizard)

I have this code:

```
class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):

def get_template_names(self):
    return [TEMPLATES[self.steps.current]]

def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        print(form_list)
        process_form_data(form_list)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('../home')

def process_form_data(form_list):
    if form.is_valid():
        form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]

        first_name = form_data[0]['first_name']
        last_name = form_data[0]['last_name']
        email = form_data[0]['email']

        fav_food = form_data[0]['fav_food']
        fav_drink = form_data[0]['fav_drink']

        user = User.objects.create_user(email)
        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name
        user.email = email
        user.save()

        user_addon = UserAddon.objects.create(user=user,fav_food=fav_food,fav_drink=fav_drink)
        user_addon.save()

        return form_data
```

If i print out form_list i get this

```
odict_values([<UserAddonForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(fav_food;fav_drink;first_name,last_name;email)>,ContactForm3 bound=True, valid=True, fields=(info1;info2;message)>])
```

and if i try running it with just

```
form.is_valid()
```

i get

```
Exception Value: name 'form' is not defined
```

how can i get an equivalent of the form.is_valid() working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a `form_list` to the function `process_form_data`, but checking against name `form` (by `form.is_valid()`) which does not exist at that point.

Assuming `form_list` is an iterable, you can iterate over it and deal with the forms sequentially:

```
def process_form_data(form_list):
    for form in form_list:
        if form.is_valid():
            form_data = form.cleaned_data
            first_name = form_data[0]['first_name']
            last_name = form_data[0]['last_name']
```

Comment: Great thank you! For the first_name, last_name, etc should that be indented under form_data = form.cleaned_data (as in under the if)? or should it be under the for?